# WordPress: Isolating posts on a certain topic, to one section of a site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

First, I've only programmed a lot of HTML, know a little PHP and am playing with Wordpress, experimenting and learning it the way I learn everything else, trial and error, heavy on the error.

The subject line isn't very clear I'm sure. I have a site set up for writing. The posts act as categories and to a Page menu for static submissions. All posts, in the theme show up on page 1, 2, etc. Great.

What I'm trying to figure out and want is this. I want a separate section of Posts just for one topic, in this case movie reviews. So the main section of the site is general posting. I want a separate section where users can post to their hearts content but have those movie posts REMAIN in one section and not be mixed in with the "general population." Ok, they click on the Movie Review link on the main page. This takes them to the Site Admin where they can write a review in TinyMCE and Publish it. IS there a way that these Posts can show up in a section of their own?

I've even installed a second WP site for this purpose. Wonderful, but now I have to transfer all registered users there and any new ones. That's insane. Plus, the user would have to log in twice, once for the original and once for the Movie WP. Also unacceptable.

If I'm on the wrong site to ask this question, let me know and my apologies. Otherwise, some guidance would keep me from my endless Google search.

Comment: This is a question about Wordpress, which I don't know. Certainly from the point of view of HTML you can do it.

Comment: Yeah, I know HTML can. It is a WordPress thing. I even know a bit of PHP, but WordPress files are VERY confusing because they're set up in sections. I used to HEADING BODY. NOTHING like WP.

Thanks for reply,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

You can use Categories to mimic this. So your movie reviews would be at mysite.com/category/movie-reviews/. You would then modify index.php to exclude the movie reviews category from the main page.

If you're comfortable with using php, you could instead use [custom post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Post_Types). This is a better solution, but would require more custom coding. The bottom of the Codex page I linked to has some excellent walkthroughs on using CPTs.

Comment: Excluding categories from your home page is indeed the way to go. If you search for these terms, you will find many examples and some plugins that allow you to do this without much effort. You could use custom post types for this, but if your PHP skills aren't that developed yet, it will be hard to get to the point where they offer more benefits.

Comment: Thank you both for the categories idea. Will do some WP Googling for examples. Yeah, I can use PHP minimally and do, on forms for example, but WordPress is another animal. I'm experimenting and playing with it every day and learning what controls what but a long process. So, my project now is to set up a Sample WP site and learn categories and index.php
Thanks soooooo much for your help. Dennis and Jan

Comment: ONE more question. I can now EXCLUDE a category from the home page with:
if (is_home()) {
        query_posts('cat=-xxx');
  }
Is there similar code to INCLUDE like 
if (is_PAGEID()) {
        query_posts('cat=+xxx');
  }
So that I could not only exclude from the home page but INCLUDE on another specific page as well?

Mike

Comment: Got it. I can now easily exclude movie reviews from the main page. I've read myself crazy but it finally sank in. Fine. Im the only creator of new posts on the front page anyway. People can comment like crazy.
BUT, I want the Movie Review page to be for EVERYONE to POST on, and to be the only place they can, nearly like a blog forum with people posting each review as a new topic. 
Again, I've read and finding only how to separate MY posts. 
--> Is it possible (with a "movies" category) to put those by default on the Movies Posting Page? 
Hope this makes sense.
-- Mike